# What is the relationship between RECV_Q of netstat and RECV BUF in tcp

Tags: tcp

I always notice that the size of RECV_Q in netstat is always smaller than RECV_BUF.
For example:
I use getsockopt method to get the RECV_BUF value of my server socket, the value is 20000.
And I block the server in this way:Only accept connection from client, but doesn't recv any data from client while client is sending data all the way.

I use commond 'sudo netstat -talunp | grep 14455'(14455 is the server pid.)
the result is that:
"""
tcp    15299      0 127.0.0.1:50005         127.0.0.1:44055         ESTABLISHED 14455/python
"""

which means that the RECV_Q is 15299 , smaller than RECV_BUF(20000)。

I am confused that what is the relationship between RECV_Q and RECV_BUF.

Answer (score 0):

If by `RECV_BUF` you mean the size of the socket receive buffer, it is the size of the socket receive buffer, where RECV_Q is the amount of data actually in it.